# pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==20.0.2' distribution was not found and is required by the application

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

```
python --version
Python 2.7.18
python3 --version
Python 3.10.0
```

After I installed pip3 using `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

I run `pip3`

It shows error below:

```bash
$ pip3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 568, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 886, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 777, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 21.2.3 (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==20.0.2'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3243, in <module>
    def _initialize_master_working_set():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3226, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3255, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 570, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 583, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 772, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==20.0.2' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

I would appreciate it if someone could provide any ideas to solve this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Running pip using sudo is strongly discouraged in the pip documentation, precisely because it can break your system. You should have upgraded your system pip using your distribution’s package manager (if they don’t have the latest version of pip yet, and that matters to you, you’d need to check with them when they will have it packaged). Or use virtual environments, which is the recommended approach.

https://discuss.python.org/t/help-needed-about-versionconflict-pkg-ressources/17991

There are many solutions discussed here:

git link : https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599#issuecomment-414157896

Please see which one fits for you.